# generate 100 pages document with consecutive numbers

Tags: variable

I need to generate a 100 pages document with only 1 number per page starting from 1 till 100. Any idea?

Comment: The number at the bottom or where?

Comment: a number in the middle of a page. The number should be inside a triangle centered horizontally and vertically in the middle of the page.

Comment: How could we guess it? Please, make a ***new*** question with the ***necessary*** details; don't wait somebody asks for the background color of the triangle or the thickness of the sides.

Comment: Sorry, my fault

Answer (score 8):

Set up a 100x loop.  All that is necessary is to leave vertical mode and clear the page, with page numbering turned on.  Once can leave vertical mode with `\leavevmode` as I did here, or with an empty `\mbox{}`, or by typing any (non-printing) character, such as `~`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach\x in{1,2,...,100}{\leavevmode\clearpage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wanted the number as actual page data, rather than as a page numbering scheme,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\foreach\x in{1,2,...,100}{\vspace*{3in}\centerline{\scalebox{10}{\x}}\clearpage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In reply to the comment about when the number of digits change, the key here would be to place the argument to `\triangled` in a fixed size box.  That way, the triangle is the same size regardless of the number of digits.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{anyfontsize} 
\usepackage{pgffor} 
\usepgflibrary{shapes} 
\newcommand*\triangled[1]{\tikz[baseline= (char.base)]{\node[regular polygon, 
  regular polygon sides=3, line width=1pt, draw, inner sep=4pt] (char) {%
  \makebox[1em]{#1}};}}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\begin{document} 
\foreach\x in{1,2,...,100}{\vspace*{-2cm}\centerline{\scalebox{10}{%
  \triangled{\x}}}\clearpage}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Seems to work. But I have a problem: I use this with a node and margin from bottom of the page change when number of digits change: \documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepgflibrary{shapes}
\newcommand*\triangled[1]{\tikz[baseline= (char.base)]{
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, line width=1pt, draw, inner sep=4pt] (char) {#1};}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\foreach\x in{1,2,...,100}{\vspace*{-2cm}\centerline{\scalebox{10}{\triangled{\x}}}\clearpage}
}\end{document}

Comment: @Sortee See my addendum at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way with centering the page numbers with respect to the page center.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\foreach \x in {1,...,100}{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[scale=45,blue] at (current page.center)  {\x};}
  \clearpage
}

\end{document}
```

[image]