# Generate a 100 page document with consecutive numbers inside a shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to generate a 100 pages document with only 1 number per page starting from 1 till 100. The number should be inside a triangle centered horizontally and vertically in the middle of the page. Any idea?

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/426138/134574) shows how to create the 100 pages, but without the number within the triangle.

Comment: Why don't you mention your previous question? It could be used as a starting point.

Comment: @samcarter thank you for pointing out to me.

Comment: @samcarter Sorry, I rushed and did it myself :/

Answer (score 6):

Based on the excellent answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426143/36296

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\foreach \x in {1,...,100}{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[scale=10,blue,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,draw=black] at (current page.center)  {\x};}
  \clearpage
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to work well. However, if I set the page in a4 and landscape mode, there's some problem: margin from the top of the page change as the number of digits change.

Comment: @Sortee Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates your problem